# What is the purpose of typealiasing common java.lang.*Exceptions in Kotlin stdlib?

Tags: exception, kotlin

Recently I was wondering which class should I inherit in Kotlin if I want to create app-specific exception.

I noticed that I can inherit both: Kotlin's own `Exception` type and `java.util.Exception`.
So, I was looking for the answers: `Exception` or `java.lang.Exception` and `Exception` or `RuntimeException` (since Kotlin does not have checked exceptions, what is the difference)? Regarding second question: I feel like it is still better to use `RuntimeException` if Kotlin code can be invoked from Java in future (please correct me if I am wrong).

Regarding `Exception` I discovered that Kotlin's version is nothing more than the `typealias` on original Java `Exception`:

> @SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias Exception = java.lang.Exception

What is the purpose of having this typealias? The only advantage I see is you do not have to `import java.lang.Exception`, which makes your source code one-line-cleaner. Wondering if there is other motivation behind such typealiasing?

Comment: I extend from the kotlin `RuntimeException` for precisely the reason you stated, that there are no checked exceptions in kotlin. I assume that there is a `typealias` of `java.lang.Exception` to decouple kotlin code from the java runtime. This makes sense given that we know jetbrains is targeting other runtimes and native code.

Comment: ^ That's the answer, this way any code that refers to the Kotlin version can be compiled to multiple platforms.

Comment: yup, this is exactly the point of [`expect` and `actual` declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) - @Dean why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically extend from `RuntimeException` for the same reason you stated yourself, that there are no checked exceptions in kotlin, but either is fine.

The reason that there is a `typealias` of the `java.lang.Exception` within the kotlin-stdlib is to decouple your kotlin code from the java runtime/platform. This is because Jetbrains target other [runtimes/platform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html). The aim is so that in theory you should be able to compile or transpile the same kotlin code to different platforms with minimal effort.